# pymongo: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: python, mongodb, dbaccess

so I'm having the weirdest problem! I have a python script which was working just fine and accessing a local mongodb and all was good.. then I wanted to add a new feature but I wanted to try it first so I copied my script into a new file and when I tried to run it it didn't access to mongodb and it kept on giving me this error `pymongo: [Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`
  **BUT** the old script is still **working** just fine!!
I searched every were google could have taken me and tried everything I know but the problem is still there all *new scripts* are giving me this error and all *old ones* are working just fine.. 
can anyone please help me?

Comment: What Operating System are you using? Maybe you have to open a port? Make sure you check your antivirus ?

Comment: Could you provide the relevant code in your old script and the relevant code in your new script for comparison, please?

Comment: @JoeA A I'm using windows 10, the port is opened I checked  for that,
but I checked the antivirus and it was blocking the script I unblocked it and it worked .. thanks ^_^
befor I checked the firewall but the antivirus didn't occur to me.. thanks a lot ^_^

Comment: That's good that the port is opened! Then there ya go I'm happy to help! I've faced that error a couple of times using Pymongo and other stuff so no worries. I'm just glad it worked :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was with the antivirus.. I have comodo antivirus and it has been blocking the scripts,, I unblocked them and now they work :)